# Python Flask render_template not rendering correctly

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

When someone logs out of my page I want to add a paragraph to HTML with Jinja saying they have successfully logged out. It works up to the point where I actually return render_template.

```
 @app.route('/logout',methods=['POST'])
    def logout():
       session['logged_in'] = False
       message = "You have successfully logged out"
       return redirect(url_for('index_page',message=message))

 @app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
 def index_page():
    try:
       session['logged_in']
       message = request.args['message']
       return render_template('index.html',message=message)
    except:
       session['logged_in'] = False
       return render_template('index.html')
```

When I print `message` in `index_page` after logging out, it correctly prints out `"You have successfully logged out"` and even if I print `render_template('index.html',message=message)` it gives a correct HTML with the `message` where it should be. But it doesn't actually render the page correctly on the screen, as if `message` was undefined.

If I define `message` withing `index_page` directly (`message = "You have successfully logged out"`), it renders correctly.

EDIT:
Thanks, I tried doing that. However, the issue is everything works fine just before rendering. Consider this code I did:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
    def index_page():    
        try:
            print("Checkpoint 1")
            message = request.args['message']
            print("Checkpoint 2")
    except:
        print("Checkpoint 3")
        message = "Other message"

    print("Checkpoint 4",message)
    #print("Checkpoint 5",render_template('index.html',message=message))
    return render_template('index.html',message=message)
```

So, when I just refresh the page (pass no message) my console output is something like:

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 3
Checkpoint 4 "Other message"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And I get the page saying "Other message"
However, if I pass a message by calling `logout` first, I get something like:

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 4 "You have successfully logged out"
"GET /?message=You+have+successfully+logged+out HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And I still get the page saying "Other message".

If I print out Checkpoint 5, it gives correct HTML with correct messages in both cases.

Notice I don't get a GET request in the form `GET /?message=something` in the first case, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Why not just use flash()?

Answer (score 0):

In general: never ever do a `try/except` catching all exceptions.

You will miss important errors, like in this case. An administrator cannot safely upgrading the program.

In this case you have a `session['logged_in']` without setting a value (in `index_page`).  I think this cause the exception (undefined item in session), so it never write the `message`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this is not the case. I redirect to `index_page` from `logout`, where I defined `session['logged_in']`. Also, if I print out `message` or `render_template('index.html',message=message)` in `index page`, I get expected outputs. Yet when I _return_ the same `render_template`, I get incorrect html rendered.

Comment: Remove the try/exception. I think you will have better error message. I'm also not sure you can use url_for(..., message) without message signature in function. But personally I'll avoid mixing GET and POST in the same route (especially here, where I think you do not need POST (also logout, BTW))

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that. However, the issue is everything works fine just before rendering. Consider this code I did (posted in the original post)